# How to change the year color and text size of a date picker

Tags: android, datepicker

I want to change only the year color and size in the header of the default android 7.0 date picker dialog. is this possible?

colorAccent and colorPrimary are changing the whole theme. I want just the year to be different.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following attribute:

```
android:headerYearTextAppearance
```

> The text appearance for the year (ex. 2014) in the selected date header.
>
> May be a reference to another resource, in the form "@[+][package:]type/name" or a theme attribute in the form "?[package:]type/name".

[Source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#attr_android:headerYearTextAppearance)

Implementation:

```
<DatePicker xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/your_datepicker"
    ...
    android:headerYearTextAppearance="@style/YourStyle"/>
```

and in your styles.xml:

```
<style name="YourStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/your_color</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">...</item>
</style>
```

Comment: @SO80 added example.

Comment: Don't know why, but this isn't working, if I'm creating datepicker dialog programmatically

Comment: @Starwave have you tried adding the theme in the constructor of your DatePicker?

Comment: Yes, to no avail.

Comment: @Starwave there can be many reasons for that. The simplest problem could be that there's another theme overriding it from somewhere else, or some support compatibility issue. It might be worth asking a new question with your code and all the relevant information